# ClickOnce application start menu shortcut disappears

Tags: clickonce

I have different versions of the same application: production, development, and test. Each one has their own solution file and separate branches in [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server). We just started using ClickOnce. Both development and test use the same PFX key for right now, but they are deployed to two separate folders.

Now when someone installs a development build, the icon in the start Menu gets installed and looks at

"company name" -> development build

This is driven by the Publish -> Options -> Description -> Publisher name and Product Name.

Now when the user goes to install Test Build, same Publisher name and different Product Name.  The start menu is removed (or overwritten) for the development build link and is replaced with the test build. Also the option in the Add/Remove Programs is whatever the last installed was.

How can I get two applications with the same publisher to create two different start menu items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need also to use different assembly names for different builds. You can modify *Assembly name* in the *Application* tab of the project's property page. They will be considered as different products after you have changed assembly name and product name.

And only the main EXE file needs to be changed, because once [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) treats it as a separate install, all the other DLL files are installed in a separate cache folder in the `<username>\AppData\Local\2.0` folder. The DLL file should not conflict with others.